# Call a function only if a value is neither null nor undefined

Tags: jquery, null, local-storage, undefined

When a button is clicked I check if something exists in a localstorage key as such:

```
var a = localStorage.getItem('foo');
if (typeof a != 'undefined') {
    // Function
}
```

but if the key doesn't exists at all, it return null. How can I call **if not undefined and not null do function**, else return true(?) or continue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JavaScript has a concept of **falsy** values... i.e. 0, `null`, `undefined` and an empty string.

Because of this, you should be able to just check if `a` is "truthy" (i.e. not one of the values I've mentioned above), by doing this:

```
var a = localStorage.getItem('foo');
if (a) {
    // Function
}
```

More information [from SitePoint available here](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/)

Answer (score 2):

You should not use JavaScript's falsy comparisons if `false`, `0`, `NaN`, or the empty string are valid values in your localStorage.

Instead you should check if the item is equal to `null` or is equal to `undefined`:

```
var a = localStorage.getItem('foo');
if (a === null || a === undefined) {
    // Function
}
```

Note that the triple equals (`===`) operator compares exactly, without **[type coercion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/359494/1248889)**. Using double equals (`==`) operator a special set of rules are applied to covert similar values but of different types. One of the most useful of these is that `null == undefined`, allowing simplification the above code:

```
var a = localStorage.getItem('foo');
if (a != null) {
    // Function
}
```

If a is `null` or `undefined` the code inside will not run.