# Fat arrow conditional in mapping

Tags: javascript, typescript

Was just wondering if in javascript or typescript there is a way to write the conditional of a fat arrow function in the element mapping itself?

Current code

```
functionName(data => {
  if(data){
  }
});
```

Is there syntax that checks `data` before it even gets to the `if` statement?

Something like

```
functionName(data? => {
   if(data){ // This code is then not needed
   }
});
```

Or

```
functionName(!data => {
   if(data){ // This code is then not needed
   }
});
```

So that it only passes into the function if `data` is falsey.

Thanks

Comment: can you do so in a "normal" function?

Comment: please add an example of what you like to do and what you like to get.

Comment: @NinaScholz - I think it wants some notation where a function is conditionally executed without an `if` or similar statement

Comment: why "not null" ... because `data` will be falsey if it is `undefined` or `0` or `''` or `false` ...  your requirement of `not null` is quite specific - anyway, what's wrong with `if (data === null) return;` as the very first statement in the function?

Comment: [There is no way, use a normal function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9906009/call-a-function-only-if-a-value-is-neither-null-nor-undefined).

Comment: So `functionName` is a function that takes another function as an argument. In that case, the function `functionName` could just implement logic to not call the argument function if `data` is null or undefined. It would be a lot easier to answer this question if you'd include a decent example though.

Comment: No there is nothing wrong with the if statement , am just curious if there is a short hand , but yeah basically like you say `falsey` not `not null` specific

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Yeah that makes sense, the component i am working with is an alert box , i am hitting the onDidDismiss of the alert which is triggered is the user clicks outside of the alert but also if the user clicks an option in the alert, so i just need to handle for both cases

Comment: Please share your implementation of `functionName`. That's probably the best place for any `null` or **falsey** checks.

Comment: @JeffreyWesterkamp well it is `handler: data => { alert.dismiss(data); }` but it is also triggered in the component itself, I guess im taking a shortcut because the correct implementation is to use buttons in the alert. Its not a huge issue, i just keep stumbling on typescript shortcuts, so was just wondering if something like this existed

Comment: Okay, the shortest way would be to _short circuit_ the `alert.dismiss` expression: `handler: (data) => { data && alert.dismiss(data) }`. This will not call `alert.dismiss` if `data` is falsey. Any call to `handler` would still execute though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically what you are doing with is calling functionName() with an anonymous arrow function as a parameter. Also the arrow function takes one parameter named data.

So when you check data?, it means you are already called functionName with an anonymous arrow function as a parameter. So basically, I don't think you can do what you asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you check the `data` before you run the function?

```
functionName(data => {
  if(data){
  }
});
```

Instead of that, we use:

```
functionName(data => {
  // do something with data
});

data && functionName(data); // call the function when data is valued
```

Basically, there have no ways to check in the function as your expectation because the function is fired and use `data` you provided as a param immediately. `data` is just used as param in your function, no more roles of outside. So While you can access the `data`, it means you are inside of the function already.

Comment: Its because the function can be triggered outside my code ( in the component ) I mean i can do a check before but it would only work with the actions on specific user actions ... I would miss one action from the user if they click outside the alert. Its not a issue really was just wondering if typescript or es had a shortcut for this, there seems to be a lot of helpful shortcuts ... so was wondering